# Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch after running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails test case was not working.

When I ran my test, it showed the following error.

```
validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.3.3,
 but your Gemfile specified 2.4.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

Comment: You'll need to either upgrade your Ruby version, or specify the version you have, as stated in the error message

Comment: how to update my Ruby version?

Comment: acutually my ruby version is 2.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add/replace the ruby version as `ruby "2.3.3"` in your Gemfile

Comment: again i got this error : -  block in materialize': Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: Your Ruby version is 2.4.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.3

Comment: You should remove `ruby "2.4.2" `. You do one thing just try `ruby -v` and check what is your ruby version. If you  using rvm check what is the version in that `rvm list`. Then set the proper version in the Gemfile.

Comment: My version is ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]

Comment: Remove the `Gemfile.lock` from  and do the `bundle install`